# How to solve this warning message: renv took longer than expected to activate the sandbox

Tags: r, rstudio, renv, r-usethis

After installing certain packages in R I got this message:

Warning message:
renv took longer than expected (20 seconds) to activate the sandbox.

The sandbox can be disabled by setting:
RENV_CONFIG_SANDBOX_ENABLED = FALSE
within an appropriate start-up .Renviron file.
See `?renv::config` for more details.

How to solve this?

> R.version
> _
> platform       x86_64-apple-darwin17.0
> arch           x86_64
> os             darwin17.0
> system         x86_64, darwin17.0
> status
> major          4
> minor          2.0
> year           2022
> month          04
> day            22
> svn rev        82229
> language       R
> version.string R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22)
> nickname       Vigorous Calisthenics

run with RStudio  Version 2023.06.1+524 (2023.06.1+524) and [renv 1.0.0]

I tried using `usethis::edit_r_environ(scope = c("user"))` (https://usethis.r-lib.org/reference/edit.html) then writing `Sys.setenv(RENV_CONFIG_SANDBOX_ENABLED = FALSE)` (https://rstudio.github.io/renv/reference/config.html) on the .Renviron file but didn't worked out.

Comment: The easiest and most reliable way of solve this is to follow the instructions in the warning message. Alternatively you can try finding out *why* copying the relevant files is taking so long on your system, but that’s often not trivial. — You seem to have tried that, but you misunderstood how the `.Renviron` file is formatted; consult [the documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html) (section *Details*).

Comment: This issue may also be resolved in renv 1.0.1 which was just released -- can you try upgrading and reporting back?

Comment: @KevinUshey I tried but didn't help

Answer (score 0):

So how to fix this is by using `usethis::edit_r_environ(scope = c("user"))` to open and edit the .Renviron file then running and saving this line `RENV_CONFIG_SANDBOX_ENABLED=FALSE` (without leading or trailing blank space around "="). Restart session and ready